# How can Outlook automatically unsubscribe me from emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I fancy unsubscribing from non-personalized emails (e.g. newsletters from tourism websites). I'm not asking about blocking, or unsubscribing from everything from, the same sender (e.g. replies from this tourism websites' staff to my emails).

I can't find [the following](https://www.lifewire.com/unsubscribe-from-newsletters-hotmail-1174263) features in Outlook.live.com or in MS Outlook 2016.

> [image]

Comment: "Will someone please screenshot the following?" - Is there a reason you cannot screenshot it yourself?

Comment: You have to open one of the emails in order to read and see Unsubscribe option

Comment: User needs to clarify what they mean exactly, as I understand it: they want personal/reply emails from tourism company, but not tourism companies newsletters. This can be accomplished via 'Unsubscribe' link at bottom of those types of emails, yet they say they don't want to unsubscribe-from-everything so maybe they are confused that the unsubscribe link is only for those newsletters? The feature they describe is managing it via rules in their email program so technically they are still getting the newsletters just tucking them away which I think is sloppier

Comment: The sweep feature only works for Outlook.com as the article & snapshot indicate, you'd want to use Rules in Outlook app to manage it a similar way

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to Outlook.com
2. Click a newsletter email
3. Click Sweep button (at very top under search)
   [image]
4. Select 'Move all messages from the Inbox folder and any future messages', OK
   [image]

**Outlook 2016 app doesn't have Sweep feature from what I can tell, below are some similar options:**

- Click email, Unsubscribe button. I believe it just clicks the Unsubscribe link usually at the bottom of the email

  [image]
- Right-click email, Junk, Block Sender
  [image]
- Right-click email, Rules, Always Move Messages From: CompanyName
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

An [Outlook Uservoice post](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/601444-new-experiences-in-outlook-com/suggestions/35174431-rule-move-all-messages-in-the-inbox-folder-and-all)
gives this advice:

> To create the **sweep** rule to move all messages from a user in the
>   Inbox folder and all future messages:
>
> 1. Select the email or emails with the senders you which to move
> 2. Click the "Sweep" Button or click "Move-to → Move all emails from"
> 3. Select the option "Move all messages from the Inbox folder and any future messages"
> 4. Choose the folder you wish to move these messages to
> 5. Click OK

Although I'm not using Outlook, I understand from the above that if you
don't see a *Sweep* button, then *Move-to* is an alternative.

Comment: I use Outlook.com and sweep has nothing to do with unsubscribing. The OP wants to stop unsolicited emails from being sent to him by removing himself from mailing lists, not to manage them when they continue to pour in. And how can "move-to" be considered a substitute for unsubscribing? It's completely unrelated!

Comment: @wrecclesham: His question was where is "Sweep", the answer (or its equivalent menu option) is above. He might have put more than one question in this one post, but I don't know of any email client that can do automatic unsubscribe, which usually includes going to a website and at least doing a click, sometimes more.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll fix the title so it matches the question.